# Java Web application start up

Tags: java, web-applications

How can I achieve the following ?

I have two Java web applications app1 and app2. 
I want that app2 should always gets loaded before app1.

Comment: Are you using tomcat or some other container? If you're using tomcat you can define that order at server.xml.

Comment: It is oracle Weblogic

Comment: answer is here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/deployment/ChangeTheServerDeploymentOrder.html